# Cyclic outputs using list comprehensions and modulo

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, list-comprehension

I am trying to get this output using list comprehensions and modulo:

```
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
```

My current code is:

```
lst = [i for i in range(10)]

for j in range(len(lst) - 1), lst:
    for i in range(1):
        lst.append(lst.pop(0))
        print(*lst)
```

How can I improve this code using modulo? Maybe even optimise it in 1 line?

Comment: `for i in range(1):` is pointless, it only runs once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be over-complicating this somewhat - this would seem to have the intended result - using [string.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). Note that we convert the members of the list to strings to enable us to use this approach.

### Code:

```
lst = [str(i) for i in range(10)]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(''.join(lst))
    lst.append(lst.pop(0))
```

### Output:

```
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
```

### Alternatively - if you want the result in one string:

```
>>> print(''.join([v for x in [lst[i:] + lst[:i] + ['\n'] for i in range(len(lst))] for v in x]))
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
```

Comment: it gives me `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/m.m/PycharmProjects/untitled9/source.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(''.join([v for x in [lst[i:] + lst[:i] + ['\n'] for i in range(len(lst))] for v in x]))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found` Error. Why is it for ?

Answer (score 2):

Fun fact that you can also do this with deque - and it will allow you to go either direction, in any increment.

```
from collections import deque
dq = deque([i for i in range(10)])

for x in range(len(dq)):
    ''.join(map(str,dq))
    dq.rotate(-1)
```

Output

```
'0123456789'
'1234567890'
'2345678901'
'3456789012'
'4567890123'
'5678901234'
'6789012345'
'7890123456'
'8901234567'
'9012345678'
```

Comment: could you explain what does deque exactly do ?

Comment: @MohVahedi it's an extension of list functionality of sort and is specifically designed for this exact use case.  Here's a sample of what you can do: https://github.com/crvaden/A-Z-of-Python/blob/master/Q.py

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I think I get your question, here is a solution with %:

```
n = 10 # You can take any number, the list will be a cycle of numbers from 0 to 9
lst = [i % 10 for i in range(n)]

for j in range(len(lst)):
    print(''.join([str(k) for k in lst]))
    lst = [(i + 1) % 10 for i in lst]
```

---

My previous answer:

An absolutely ugly one with `itertools.cycle()`

```
import itertools

lst = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
cpt, turn = 0, 0

for char in itertools.cycle(lst):
    if turn >= len(lst):
        break
    if cpt >= len(lst):
        cpt = 0
        turn += 1
        print()
    else:
        print(char, end='')
        cpt += 1
```